# Macro not working for fetching data from Active Directory

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I changed my laptop and below given macro is not working in it. where as in my old machine it is still working. I cross checked all the references and enable it as per my old machine. I also cross checked with some other guys and they told me to use ADODB.Connection line in below code.

Also When I checked macro line by line items by pressing F8 key its is showing blank in "idapstr" line where as in old machine when using same macro its working fine.
Error code is on below line code "Set x = GetObject(ldapstr)" is mentioned below :-
**
" run time Error -2147023541 (8007054b)
Automation Error
The Specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."**

Can anybody help me out how to add the "ADODB.Connection" code or how to adjust this existing code ?

```vb
Public Sub UpdateResourceInfoNew()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim auxDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim rw As IHTMLTableRow
    Dim table1 As IHTMLTable
    Dim x As IADs
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim lr As Excel.ListRow
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Column
    Dim signum, name, ldapstr, relation As String
    Dim urlText As Variant
    Dim keyVal As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("ASSIGNMENTS")
    
    Dim responseDict As Dictionary
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Did you updated the Authorization Key in sheet ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    
    If answer = vbYes Then
    
        Set lo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ASSIGNMENTS").ListObjects("ASSIGNMENTS")
        
        For Each lr In lo.ListRows
            Set rng = lr.Range
            signum = UCase(rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("SIGNUM").Index).Value)
            name = rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("NAME").Index).Value
            updateFlag = rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("UPDATE_RES_INFO").Index).Value
            
            
            If signum <> "" And updateFlag = 1 Then
                ldapstr = "LDAP://CN=" & signum & ",OU=CA,OU=User,OU=P001,OU=ID,OU=Data,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=se"
                Set x = GetObject(ldapstr)
                x.GetInfoEx Array("CN", "displayName", "givenName", , "email", "sn", "homePhone", "title", "department", "company", "l", "Manager", "country"), 0
                auxCN = UCase(x.Get("CN"))
                If (auxCN = signum) Then
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("SIGNUM").Index).Value = UCase(signum)
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("NAME").Index).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(x.Get("displayName"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("RELATION").Index).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(x.Get("homePhone"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("TITLE").Index).Value = x.Get("title")
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("DEPARTMENT").Index).Value = UCase(x.Get("department"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("COMPANY").Index).Value = UCase(x.Get("company"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("COUNTRY").Index).Value = UCase(x.Get("country"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("LAST NAME").Index).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(x.Get("sn"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("FIRST NAME").Index).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(x.Get("givenName"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("E-MAIL").Index).Value = x.Get("mail")
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("HOME BASE").Index).Value = UCase(x.Get("l"))
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("UPDATE_RES_INFO").Index).Value = 2
                    
                    Set responseDict = New Dictionary
                    url_prefix = "XXXXXXX"
                    
                    url_suffix = signum_rng
                    
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    
                    On Error Resume Next
                    
                    Dim returnVal As String
                    
                    Dim httpObject As Object, item As Object
                    Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    
                    URL = url_prefix & Trim(signum)
                    
                    sAuthorization = Worksheets("Authentication key").Range("G4").Value
                    
                    httpObject.Open "GET", URL, False
                    httpObject.setRequestHeader "Authorization", sAuthorization & EncodeBase64
                    httpObject.Send
                    sGetResult = httpObject.responseText
                    
                    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                        .Open "GET", URL, False
                        .Send
                        urlText = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(.responseText, "{", ""), "[", ""), "}", ""), "]", ""), ",""")
                    End With
                    
                    responseDict.RemoveAll
                    
                    For i = 0 To UBound(urlText)
                        urlText(i) = Replace(urlText(i), Chr(34), "")
                        keyVal = Split(urlText(i), ":")
                        responseDict.Add keyVal(0), keyVal(1)
                    Next i
                    
                    If Split(urlText(34), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(34), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("PERSONNEL NUMBER").Index).Value = Split(urlText(34), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(11), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(11), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("JOB ROLE").Index).Value = Split(urlText(11), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(30), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(30), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("POSITION NAME").Index).Value = Split(urlText(30), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(4), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(4), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("LINE MANAGER").Index).Value = Split(urlText(4), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(38), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(38), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                    
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("COUNTRY").Index).Value = Split(urlText(38), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(22), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(22), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("MOBILE").Index).Value = Split(urlText(22), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    If Split(urlText(32), ":")(1) <> "null" Or Len(Split(urlText(32), ":")(1)) <> 0 Then
                        rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("COST CENTRE").Index).Value = Split(urlText(32), ":")(1)
                    End If
                    
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                
                Else
                    rng.Cells.Columns(lo.ListColumns("UPDATE_RES_INFO").Index).Value = 3
                End If
            End If
        
            DoEvents
        Next lr
        
        MsgBox ("RP Updated")
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Please update the Authorization Key first"
    End If

End Sub
```

I am trying to fetch few columns details from Active Directory based on user name in our code we are using as "Signum", due to basic user of VBA I am not able to find out the issue so come to this forum if any user any help me out.

Comment: `url_suffix` is declared and given a value, but never used. Its value is given by `signum_rng`, which is not declared. This may be contributing to your issue.

Comment: `Text <> "null" Or Len(Text) <> 0`  is a redundant expression which always returns `True`. An empty string is not "null", and any string, even "null" will have a length greater than 0. I think you meant `Text <> "null" And Len(Text) <> 0`

Comment: Or you meant `vbNullString` which is not the same as a literal string "null"

Comment: Hi @Toddleson,  Actually this macro was written by one of team member who left. and it is running successfully in now as well but in old laptops which my other team members are using. and recently my office provided me new laptop where it is not working.

Comment: I tried to use F8 as well remove the "On Error Resume Next" to find the exact error . and error is "run time Error -2147023541 (8007054b) Automation Error The Specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.".